# C++ POSIX OO Cross Platform Library for use across languages and compilers

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cygwin, integrity

This is my first question here, so I apologies for any mistakes and will try to be as specific as possible. 
We need to develop a C++ POSIX OO Cross Platform Library for use across languages and compilers. Since we need to be able to use this library on different Operating Systems, for example Windows, Linux and Android, and on some embedded OS like Integrity as well, we decided to develop it under the Cygwin or Mingw. The Library itself is going to be a C++ Object Oriented code, POSIX standard. As I have already mentioned, we need to able to load and use this library across different languages. So in order to be able of using this library from managed code, we think about wrapping it with the unmanaged MS Visual C++ code first. Here we are going to face with a wide range of problems. Visual C++ uses different compiler and as a result it is almost impossible mission to link a C++ OO Library compiled under Cygwin/Mingw. The main issue is the name mangling and follows by different structure alignment issues, conflict of underlying exception and memory models. 
The other option is to have the same code but compile it with different compilers, for example Cygwin and MS Visual C++. The problem of this option is that Visual C++ compiler doesn't support POSIX.

So, does anybody encountered the same issue? Any ideas of how to develop such a library or at least to reuse the code for different compilers?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You have to compile from source, there's no general binary compatibility in C++ world. And you will need platform specific code for different platforms. Study existing frameworks, such as Qt.

Comment: Thanks Hyde, I continued to look for the possible solutions, and you absolutely right there is no binary compatibility in C++ world. I'm familiar with the Qt framework, but unfortunately we cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to provide "flattened" C wrappers of C++ classes (this concept is borrowed in large part from Rudy Velthuis: see http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html). To flatten a class, create a C function for each class member function as well as the constructor and destructor. The C wrapper for the constructor returns a pointer to an object of that class. The wrappers for the other member functions, including the destructor, take this pointer as their first argument. These C wrappers must have the extern "C" declaration are exported by the DLL and provide indirect access to the C++ objects (more details here: http://www.aaronreeves.com/windows-dlls-part-3). As a result, to outside word such a DLL will look like a DLL that is written in C. And DLLs written in C work very nicely with EXEs from a variety of sources.